# How to create a calendar using XML

Tags: xml

How to create a calendar using XML

Comment: <calendarEntry><day>1</day><month>1</month><year>1998</year></calendarEntry> :-)

Comment: Do you call that a "question" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of "using xml" to create a calendar would by to use **configuration xml files**, like this [flash Calendar](http://www.flashcomponents.net/component/flash_calendar_xml.html?ref=phils), where all the images and text are loaded from an easy-to-edit XML file.

However simple ini files might be as effective, and easier to edit ;)

You may think about some xml format representing a Calendar, knowing that [XSD might transform it](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/200408/post70290.html) into a Calendar, but for that, we ought to know more about your expected output format.

For instance, Microsoft does have a [Calendar element, which represents calendar data when you save a project in the XML format.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968563.aspx)
That can give you a good example of xml format for such a Data.

Answer (score 0):

```
I tried this code

    <CalendarView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/calendarView"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```